# How are the domain accounts existing even after the deletion of the domain controller?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group, domaincontroller

When I promote the windows server to a domain controller, the local accounts were inaccessible in the server, but when i De-promote the domain controller to the normal server the local accounts were accessible.  So where the local accounts of the server would be stored after promoting it as a DC? And even after the deletion of the active directory i can logon to the client machines with the domain user account, how it is possible?  Why those domain accounts weren't deleted??

Comment: has nothing to do here, serverfault question

Comment: Here's an even better forum to ask this type of question in the future:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you promote a normal server to Domain Controller, the local groups and users will become domain groups and users located in the **Builtin** container, they are stored in the AD database.

If you remove the DC to a normal member server, then the local users & groups will be restored like before, but the other domain users will become unaccessible since the ad database has been removed. The reason you can use a domain user to logon the client machine is the domain users' credentials and passwords are **cached locally**. In case when the DC is unavailable when you login, the OS will permit you login use the cached domain users credentials. But it is only restricted to the domain accounts which have cached before, you cannot use the accounts that haven't been cached to login the client machine.

Comment: And another doubt, can we access local user accounts in DC..?

Comment: No, as noted all the local users become domain users after promoting to DC. You can only access them after you demote that domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you promote the server to a domain controller, you change the whole authentication method of the server. Instead of the built-in Windows authentication mechanism the active directory authentication is installed (which overrides the built-in one, but does not completely replace it, it still remains on the system but will not get used anymore).

That means, your local user accounts are still there (and even still active), but they are not longer being taken into account when logging in, because the AD-authentication only looks for the accounts in the active directory.

After reducing the server back to normal, the AD-auth is uninstalled, and the built-in authentication is used again, evaluating your still existing local user accounts.

Comment: thank you very much @Psi now i had an idea about the local and domain users in the active directory.. :)